# when a user logs in to a single location they are greeted with a questionnaire

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6

Using Orchard 1.6 I am creating a application where the user creates an account and books a room for an evening.

If they choose, they can login later from other locations to double check or amend their booking.

BUT When they get to the reception area of the B&B they can login themselves on the reception computer. When they login (from the b&b computer only) a pop-up appears saying 'Welcome' and a link navigating the user to a questionnaire loads.

I only want the questionnaire to be viewable from the b&b computer, and only when the user logs in.

How is this done....a cookie perhaps? or using the IP of the computer?

Comment: Why don't you have a separate login screen just for the B&B - http://example.com/in-bb then you can see if the user logged in from that screen on your next page? Obviously you'd have that as home page or similar on your B&B computer.

Comment: good thinking bat man...will look into it